# Saving Program Data in C#

Tags: c#

So I'm working on a quick program for my mom. It has a `textbox` user input, a `combobox` for category selection, and multiple `textbox` for representing each category. The idea is that she can input a number value into the `textbox` and select a category. Then that value is stored in its respective category's `textbox`. I am absolutely certain I did not write this code well, but I don't know C# very well. Long story short, I need a way to be able to save the data stored in the `textbox` categories so she can close the program. I've never worked with something like this before, even in other languages, so this is foreign to me.

EDIT:

Here is the code illustrating what I am currently doing (this code is under a button click action, `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`:

```
        string userInput;
        userInput = textBox1.Text;

        if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            category1Box.AppendText(userInput +"\n");
        }
```

I did not specify how I wanted to save the data , as I'm not even sure how I want to do it. Like I said, I'm not experienced in this area at all, so I don't even know what the different options I had were. Hopefully this edit helps.

Comment: Post the code you wrote so we can take a look or nobody can help you.

Comment: Please provide short but complete example illustrating your problem and your code

Comment: It sounds like you just want the values she chooses to "stick" in the user interface after she closes and re-opens the application.  Is that correct?

Comment: Where you want to save data? On a simple text file? On database? On json file? XML file?

Comment: You need a way of saving the data, so database, xml file, text file will all work.  Depends what's good for your solution.  Pick how you want to do it then update with where you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

[Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27.aspx) is a fairly simple way to save and load data on a single machine. You mention a single user so I think this will fit your requirements, but without more information I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very ambiguous in terms of how you want to save data, so I'll go with a very simple solution. You can utilize a few methods in the File class in System.IO.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] data)
File.WriteAllLines(string path, string[] data)
File.WriteAllText(string path, string data)
```

These methods are very useful, and I suggest you learn to use them!

Comment: I'm assuming you can achieve the opposite effect by using "File.ReadAllBytes"?

Comment: I feel like this will work fine for my current project, thanks! One last question: In the parameter, of say, the "WriteAllLines" method, what does it mean by "path"? the path of the file destination?

Comment: Yup! That's where the application is going to save the file. If you need to get the startup location of the application, you can use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;